# QtMenubar Call Slot

Tags: c++, qt, qmenubar

This is inside a Menu class.  The problem is addAction.  This works, but there is no connection to slot:

```
QMenu* menu2 = new QMenu("Test");
menu2->addAction("Test");
```

When I do this:

```
QMenu* menu2 = new QMenu("Test");
menu2->addAction("Test", Menu, test);
```

I get compiler error: "error: expected primary-expression before ',' token"

I mean to call the `test()` function in the Menu class.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error comes from passing `Menu` as an argument. You say `Menu` is a class, and classes are not expressions on themselves.

If you need to call `test` on an instance of `Menu`, where `Menu` is not a derivate from `QObject` (ie. no slots available), then you can just create a slot in the widget that contains the `QMenu` itself (probably a `QMainWindow`), and implement the call in there!

Edit: to add an example.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT
 // Usual declarations...

private slots:
  void myCustomSlot();
};
```

Now, say that you're populating the main window inside its constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(...) {
   // Some initialization code

   QMenu *menu2 = new QMenu("Test");
   menu2->addAction("Test", this, SLOT(myCustomSlot));
   // Some more initialization code
}

// ...

void MainWindow::myCustomSlot() {
   instanceOfMenu->test();
}
```

Of course, if you're creating the menu outside that class, you'd need to make the slot public, but that's another issue

Comment: How do I do this? " then you can just create a slot in the widget that contains the QMenu itself (probably a QMainWindow), and implement the call in there"

Comment: Assuming your main widget is a `QMainWindow`, then you'd need to subclass the `QMainWindow` into something like `class MyQMainWindow : public QMainWindow { Q_OBJECT ... blahblah ... }`. You add the custom slot to that class and then make your main widget an instance of `MyQMainWindow` instead of `QMainWindow`. This is fairly standard stuff in Qt :) - you may actually be doing it already!